# How to refresh Android listview evry 10 seconds

Tags: android, listview, refresh

Im very new on Android. im making this [teturial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) but i have a problem on refresh and can't understand how to refresh my listview

```
        // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });


/** REFRESH HERE /** 

 Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e(TAG, "EVRY 10 SECOND START NOW ");

                            listView.invalidateViews();
                            listView.refreshDrawableState();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//                                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(movieList));

                            // fire the event

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
```

i try all methods google... but no luck this notifyDataSetChanged() not working ...

```
 listView.invalidateViews();
listView.refreshDrawableState();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Do you want to request again the web service you are hitting?

Comment: Yes make new request and get new json with new items

Comment: you can use timer to call webservice after 10s and then onResponse() refresh your listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Volley request code inside a method, let's name id `fetchData();`

Then you can call your service again after 10 seconds by the below code:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Write your code here to call the method.
                              fetchData();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception here
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Try this and lo let me know if any problem.

Comment: adapter.getData().clear(); before refresh i clean the data and its works before i got loop thank you

Comment: happy to help, Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Handler and its postDelayed method to invalidate the list's adapter as follows:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10 * 1000);
        }
    }, 10 * 1000);
```

You must only update UI in the main (UI) thread.

By creating the handler in the main thread, you ensure that everything you post to the handler is run in the main thread also.

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer:

```
 Timer timerAsync;
 TimerTask timerTaskAsync;

timerAsync = new Timer();
        timerTaskAsync = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doWork();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timerAsync.schedule(timerTaskAsync, 1000, 5000);// First Start 1 seconds 5 seconds repeat
```